# Replacing and restoring div html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I have a couple of functions, the first replaces the contents of a div the second restores the original div. The problem is because I'm using the replaceWith method, the second div no longer exists if I try to call it a second time. Is there a better way to do this? I've experimented creating a variable that stores the contents of the second div so I can resuse it, but could not get it to work.

The code that I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#trigger_adults').click(function() {
    var mainClone = $("#main-content").clone();

    $('#main-content').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#main-content').replaceWith($('#adults'));
        $('#slider-sec').slideUp('slow');
        $('#adults').fadeIn('fast');
        $(window).scrollTop(0);

    });

    $('#return').click(function() {

        $("#adults").replaceWith(mainClone.clone());
        $('#adults').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#slider-sec').slideDown('slow');

        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you create a code-snippet?

Comment: try adding `mainClone.fadeIn()` to the second function.

Answer (score 1):

You could have both contents in the same div and toggle the visibility of their parent divs. Use javascript just to toggle the wrapper's class.

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#wrapper').toggleClass('init-state new-state');
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.init-state #new,
.new-state #init { display:none; }
.inner {
  padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="init-state">
  <div id="init" class="inner">Initial Content</div>
  <div id="new" class="inner">New Content</div>
  <button id="toggle" type="button">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page

you either need to manually set the display style property back to its original value, or call jQuery's `.fadeIn()` function which will do the opposite of `.fadeOut()`